# Sort by one column, then group by another, in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

This is a sort of an opposite question from ones I could find with similar wording, such as:

- [Pandas - group by one column, sort by another, get value from the third column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56399073/pandas-group-by-one-column-sort-by-another-get-value-from-the-third-column)
- [How to group by one column and sort the values of another column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666126/how-to-group-by-one-column-and-sort-the-values-of-another-column)

Say, I have this DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'model': ['Punto', 'Doblo', 'Panda', 'Doblo','Punto', 'Tipo'] ,
  'timestamp': ['20200124_083155', '20200124_122052', '20200124_134350', '20200124_150801', '20200124_163540', '20200124_195955']
})
print(df)
```

This prints out:

```
   model        timestamp
0  Punto  20200124_083155
1  Doblo  20200124_122052
2  Panda  20200124_134350
3  Doblo  20200124_150801
4  Punto  20200124_163540
5   Tipo  20200124_195955
```

What I would like to obtain is: first sort by timestamp; then in order of appearance in that sort, group by order of appearance - but without the extra "group" columns that the pandas `.groupby` clause would add; that is, I would like to obtain the final output:

```
   model        timestamp
0  Punto  20200124_083155
1  Punto  20200124_163540
2  Doblo  20200124_122052
3  Doblo  20200124_150801
4  Panda  20200124_134350
5   Tipo  20200124_195955
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Isn't the result just sorted `df` dataframe or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is possible by ordered categoricals, set order by sorted `timestamp` values in first step and then sorting by both columns by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
c = df.sort_values('timestamp')['model'].unique()

df['model'] = pd.Categorical(df['model'], ordered=True, categories=c)

df = df.sort_values(['model','timestamp'])
print (df)
   model        timestamp
0  Punto  20200124_083155
4  Punto  20200124_163540
1  Doblo  20200124_122052
3  Doblo  20200124_150801
2  Panda  20200124_134350
5   Tipo  20200124_195955
```